# how to write unit test case for validation using jest and enzyme in react js

Tags: jestjs

I am new to react js and testing framework like jest and enzyme. Please help me to write test cases for validation with setting the errors. Thanks in advance.

```js
checkCustIdInput(custId) {
    let err = '';
    if (isIdFirstLetter(custId)) {
         err = 'custid should start with g,s,t,f';
    } else if (isIdmiddleLetters(custId)) {
         err = 'please enter numbers';
    } else if (isIdLenght(custId)) {
         err = 'max char allowed is 9';
    }
    return err;
}
```

I have tried the following code:

```js
it('checkCustIdInput()', () => {
    const id={custid:'g123456j'}
    const wrapper = shallow(<ForgotId handle={jest.fn()}/>);
    wrapper.setState({ custid: 'g123456j' });
    wrapper.instance().checkCustIdInput({ id});
    expect(wrapper.state.id).toBe('1234567');
    expect(wrapper.state.error).not.toBe('');});
});
```

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: yes added @Scorpioo590

Comment: Can you show us the complete code for `ForgotSingtelId`?

Comment: No. its too lengthy @mgarcia